# Do I need individual connections to +5 V for this circuit?

Tags: voltage, flipflop, wire, series

I have the following circuit:

[image]

See that +5V in the top left corner (ignore the bottom one for now)? It is connected to J, S, J, and S. I know that I can simply grab 4 wires and connect each on to my +5V on my protoboard, but I was wondering - instead of using 4 long wires, can I just use 1 long wire, connect it from my voltage source to some spot on my breadboard, and then connect 4 wires in series (same row) to it to grab +5V? Or would this reduce the voltage each port receives?

Comment: 1) Even better, if the pins to J, S, K, and R are next to each other, you could connect them to each other with really short wires and have just one wire going to +5. If you're *really* lucky, the chip's Vcc pin will be next to them as well. 2) Are you using soldered proto-board or a breadboard that you push wires and components into?

Answer (score 2):

The schematic is drawn that way to avoid crossing wires and improve clarity. All 5 V pins will be fed from the same power supply.

When digital chips change output state (low to high or high to low) there is often a sudden very short spkike in current demand. For this instant resistance and inductance of the PCB or wiring can cause a drop in voltage to the chip and this can cause intermittent or incorrect operation. To solve this we add a small decoupling capacitor - typically 100 nF - as close to between the chip V+ and GND as we can. This supplies the current for that instant.

The problem becomes more severe at high clock speeds. For your application it may not matter but always add the decoupling capacitors to avoid trouble.

---

From the comments:

> I was just wondering if I can connect 5 wires (1 from the +5V and the other 4 from the chip) in series to draw the same voltage to each pin through each wire.

Sorry, I understood the question but didn't answer it well. Yes, you can loop from one to the next *et cetera*. Since the currents are miniscule no significant voltage drop will result. In any case, the logic thresholds are generally well towards Vcc/2 which gives quite a bit of noise immunity.

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here. I understand why the diagram is written that way, I was just wondering if I can connect 5 wires (1 from the +5V and the other 4 from the chip) in series to draw the same voltage to each pin through each wire.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, this way of connecting the pins should not be called "in series". "In series" is a name used for another kind of connections.

Comment: Yes, "daisy-chained" might be a better description.

Answer (score 2):

They are electronically almost the same thing. At the current this would take, there is no significant difference. The wire would act like a resistor of almost 0 ohms. Negligible. As the wire size decreases and the current increase across each node, then the resistance is more significant and would need to be accounted for. This happens in parallel led setups like 12V led strips. But not here.

Your breadboard does this. Each spot in a row is a slightly different distance from the source, but the resistance difference is so small it's negligible.

FYI. This type of connection is called a Daisy Chain.

Comment: So then I can add any number of wires to the one wire connected to the +5V and each wire would still draw 5V of power through it?

Comment: Depending on the current draw,  yes. These are logic signal inputs and not power sources.

Comment: ^ This is my question in simplest form. It's a fundamental quesiton of circuits - does 1 voltage source get split up over multiple wires?

Answer (score 0):

Most breadboards have two rails along each long edge specifically for power distribution.  Typically, one rail would be used for the positive supply, while the other rail is used for Ground.